# Angle based orientation ns2 not working

Tags: ns2

I'm trying to orient the nodes in ns2 using angles. It's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
set ns [new Simulator]

set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

set n 4

set router1 [$ns node]
set router2 [$ns node]
$ns duplex-link $router1 $router2 45Mb 75ms DropTail

set x_sndr 50
set x_rcvr 300

set offset 45

set angle [expr -1*$offset*$n/2]

$ns duplex-link-op $router1 $router2 orient right

for {set i 1} {$i <= $n} {incr i} {
    set sndr($i) [$ns node]
    set rcvr($i) [$ns node]
    $ns duplex-link $router1 $sndr($i) 10Mb 10ms DropTail
    $ns duplex-link $router2 $rcvr($i) 10Mb 10ms DropTail

    set angle [expr $angle+$offset]
    puts "$angle"
    $ns duplex-link-op $router2 $rcvr($i) orient ($angle)
    $ns duplex-link-op $sndr($i) $router1 orient (-1*$angle)
}

$ns duplex-link-op $router1 $router2 orient right

$ns 
close $
exec nam out.
exit 0
```

In the for loop I'm setting duplex-link-op to orient in a particular way, using angles. No matter what values I put for angles, the orientation does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Finally answering my own question,

The documentation of NS2/NAM is not proper and does not properly tell how to use angles as attributes to orient the links.

As shown on [this](http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node634.html) page, it just says this

> The  may be one of the following: orient, color, queuePos,
> label. Orient or the link orientation defines the angle between the
> link and horizontal. The optional orientation values may be difined in
> degrees or by text like right (0), right-up (45), right-down (-45),
> left (180), left-up (135), left-down (-135), up (90), down (-90). The
> queuePos or position of queue is defined as the angle of the queue
> line with horizontal. Examples for each attribute are given as
> following :
>
> `$ns duplex-link-op orient right      ;# orientation is set as right. The order`
>                                     `;# in which links are created in nam`
>                                     `;# depends on calling order of this function. $ns duplex-link-op color "green" $ns duplex-link-op`
> `queuePos 0.5 $ns duplex-link-op label "A"`

But in reality you need to orient by appending the word deg to the angle value

Eg: `$ns duplex-link-op orient 90` should be `$ns duplex-link-op orient 90deg`

So the code will be as follows:

```
set ns [new Simulator]

set nf [open out.nam w]
$ns namtrace-all $nf

set n 4

set router1 [$ns node]
set router2 [$ns node]
$ns duplex-link $router1 $router2 45Mb 75ms DropTail

set x_sndr 50
set x_rcvr 300

set offset 45

set angle [expr -1*$offset*$n/2]

$ns duplex-link-op $router1 $router2 orient right

for {set i 1} {$i <= $n} {incr i} {
    set sndr($i) [$ns node]
    set rcvr($i) [$ns node]
    $ns duplex-link $router1 $sndr($i) 10Mb 10ms DropTail
    $ns duplex-link $router2 $rcvr($i) 10Mb 10ms DropTail

    set angle [expr $angle+$offset]
    puts "$angle"
    $ns duplex-link-op $router2 $rcvr($i) orient [expr $angle]deg
    $ns duplex-link-op $sndr($i) $router1 orient [expr -1*$angle]deg
}

$ns duplex-link-op $router1 $router2 orient right

$ns 
close $
exec nam out.
exit 0
```